# Bintray gradle plugin not uploading artifacts

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle, bintray

I am using bintray gradle plugin to upload java artifact on Bintray. I have written this code from example, it creates package and version successfully but there are not files in files directory. What am I missing here??

```
bintray {
    user = 'user name'
    key = 'my key'
    pkg {
        repo = 'androids'
        name = 'name'
        licenses = ['Apache-2.0']
        vcsUrl = 'https://github.com/bintray/gradle-bintray-plugin.git'
        version {
            name = 'version'
            desc = 'Gradle Bintray Plugin 1.0 final'
            released  = new Date()
            vcsTag = '1.3.0'
            attributes = ['gradle-plugin': 'com.use.less:com.use.less.gradle:gradle-useless-plugin']
        }

        filesSpec {
            from 'build/libs'
            into 'standalone_files/level1'
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you upload it to bintray ? What step did you follow to publish ?

Comment: Should I upload it manually on Bintray? What's the purpose of plugin then?

Comment: I followed this https://github.com/bintray/gradle-bintray-plugin

Comment: You have to execute the bintray upload using gradle

Comment: I did and I wrote "it creates package and version successfully" but there are no jars in files section.

Comment: Follow this https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency/en it has a clear explanation regarding upload to jcenter()

Comment: This is not the answer.

Comment: If its an answer I would not have commented. I don't know what all you did to upload to bintray and your question is unclear. Did you set your bintray credentials in the script ? The script is just for building your package not uploading it.

Comment: If I haven't set the credential, how will it make package and version on my account? For uploading I executed the task and that's what they say.

Comment: Did you add the pom script ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122888/discussion-between-mallaudin-and-ashik-vetrivelu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was running the task from root project where build directory was not defined. When I ran it from with in the module where (build/libs) contains required artifacts.

Answer (score 1):

From your tag I assume you are working on an Android project. I had a similar problem. Then I realized `build/lib` from the plugin documentation is just a placeholder. I had to set mine to where my library's aar was stored:

```
filesSpec {
    from 'build/outputs/aar'
    into '.'
}
```

If you're ever unclear you can always just upload current directory, see what actually gets uploaded to Bintray, and then get a gauge of where it's actually looking:

```
filesSpec {
    from '.'
    into '.'
}
```

Comment: thanks @tir38 for you answer. I have solved it, but I will try your suggestion too.